# how to send link with email using node js and express

Tags: node.js, express, email-attachments, mailgun

I am unable to send click able link via email . Here is my code

```
const data = {
  from: "me@samples.mailgun.org",
  to: email,
  subject: "password reset",
  html: `
  <h1>Hey  ,we received you have to reset your account password ,${currentDate} </h1>
  <h1> Please click on the link to reset your password </h1>\
  <a href=${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/resetpassword/${token}> click here </a>

  ` ,
};
```

Mail is successfully sent to the email but the link is not clickable
It looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add `"` for `href` property:

```html
<a href="${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/resetpassword/${token}"> click here </a>
```

Comment: I see. `process.env.CLIENT_URL` and `token` are well defined? How are you setting their values?

Comment: CLIENT_URL= http://localhost:3000
token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);